# comboBoxValue To TextBox C# WINFORMS

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0, combobox, textbox

What's wrong with my code? o.O?`textBox11.Text = comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();`

I want that I will display what I will choose from comboBox10. So If I put Male in my combobox
automatically my textbox will update and will be inserted male.

NOTE;*** Is it okay if I put to my textbox to readonly so that no one can tyoe there?

Comment: try this comboBox10.Text instead of comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be ok.  Make you are using the ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event to update that textbox.